# EOF and openssl passwd

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I'm trying to make the following script in Ubuntu 11.
I'm a novice in this ... The script should receive parameters.
What I intend is, as a test, create two users, move a series of files, and assign a password by default, which will be the same login, and force change it once you log in.
I would like it to be encrypted, but I do not know how to pass that encrypted password to a command, for example to usermod -p, or assign a variable with the output of the command.
Since I do not get it, another option is to assign it with passwd using EOF so that it is not done interactively. So I use it in the way I indicated it, but I do not know how it is done that does not set the password I want.
Somebody can help me? Thank you very much

```
#!/bin/bash
usuario=`whoami`
if [ $usuario != "root" ]; then
   echo El script tiene que ejecutarse con usuario root
   exit 1
fi
if [ $# -lt 3 ]; then
   echo Número de parámetros insuficiente
   exit 2
fi
groupadd "$3"
useradd  -m -g "$3" $1
useradd  -m -G "$3" $2
echo " Usuarios y grupo creados "
cp /var/backups/*  /home/"$1"
echo " Copia de backups realizada "
mv /home/"$1"/*bak /home/"$2"
passwd -e $1 && passwd $2<<EOF
$1
$1
$2
$2
EOF

#clave1=`openssl passwd -crypt "$1"`
#clave2=`openssl passwd -crypt "$2"`
#usermod -p clave1 $1
#usermod -p clave2 $2
#openssl passwd -crypt "$2" | usermod -p "$2" $2
```

The last 5 lines, are comments, rather attempts to create an encrypted key

Comment: reduce your code the minimal code that illustrates the problem, Only one user, no attempt to create encrypted key. Good luck.

Comment: BTW, the "snippet" button is for code that can be run in a browser. Use the `{}` button in the editor for more generic syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet to pass the encrypted password to useradd.

You can get an encrypted password using the chpasswd command.

```
echo ":plaintextpassword" | chpasswd -S
```

The : is required as it separated a balnk user from the new password in the input to chpasswd.

Then everything after the : in the output that can be stored in the script and passed to useradd:

```
pwd='encryptedpasswd'
useradd -m -p "${pwd}" "${user}"
```

Comment: `$pwd = 'whatever'` is not a valid assignment in POSIX shell or its derivatives such as bash -- the `$` on the left-hand side isn't permitted, and neither are the spaces around the `=`.

Comment: @Charles - Yep, your right, fixed the post, too many different languages.